# mod_rewrite: insert index.php if URL contains X

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use **mod_rewrite** to change:

```
http://example.com/?wpdmact=process&did=m5d4FG3
```

to:

```
http://example.com/index.php?wpdmact=process&did=m5d4FG3
```

I just want to insert `index.php`.

Here is the code I have tried, but that is not working:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} wpdmact=process&did=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?wpdmact=process&did=%1 [R=301,L]
```

I have successfully created the following similar redirect on this same site:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page_id=(.*)&preview=true
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?page_id=%1 [R=301,L]
```

I have a Wordpress site that has a static `index.html` in the root folder along with `index.php`. This is to have a lighter, faster loading homepage. The only challenges this has created are the two I'm mentioning here. It breaks because in these instances the site redirects to `index.html`, instead of `index.php`.

I don't do a lot of work with mod_rewrite, so any help you can offer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} wpdmact=process&did= [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [R=301,L]
```

`QUERY_STRING` is automatically carried over to new URL.

Comment: [QSA] is to be used, i.e. query string attached

Comment: @AtulGupta: That is a misconception with many developers but its not true. `QSA` is needed only when query string is altered in rewrite rule.